# Como eu passo um vetor de struct por parâmetro de referência?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

(1) Na Função checar_enquete ela não está imprimindo os valores corretos que eu estou lendo na função ler_dados, está imprimindo um monte de números e símbolos aleatórios.
(2)Caso resolva o problema, como eu consigo imprimir todas as enquetes ja feitas?[image: Erro]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
typedef struct
{
char nome[10],sexo[10],estado_civil[12],grau[12],canal[10];
int idade,horario;
} ENQUETE;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
ENQUETE ler[10];
int i=0,opcao;
printf("\n-------------------- ENQUETE IBOPE --------------------\n");
while(1)
{
    menu();
    printf("\n Opção: ");
    scanf("%d",&opcao);
    if (opcao == 3) break;
    switch(opcao)
    {
    case 1:
        ler_dados(&ler[i]);
        break;
    case 2:
        checar_enquete(ler[i]);
        break;
    case 3:
        return 0;
        break;
    }
  i=i+1;
}
}
void menu()
{
printf("\n----------------------- MENU --------------------------\n");
printf("\n Digite 1 para realizar uma nova enquete\n");
printf("\n Digite 2 para Checar as enquetes\n");
printf("\n Digite 3 para SAIR\n");
}
void ler_dados(ENQUETE *read)
{
fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite o Nome: ");
gets(read->nome);
printf("\n Digite a idade: ");
scanf("%d",&read->idade);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite o sexo(Masculino,Feminino ou Outro): ");
gets(read->sexo);
printf("\n Digite o Estado Civil(Solteiro,Casado,Viúvo ou Divorciado): ");
gets(read->estado_civil);
printf("\n Digite o Grau de Instrução(Fundamental,Médio,Superior,\n Mestrado 
ou Doutorado): ");
gets(read->grau);
printf("\n Digite o Horário da entrevista: ");
scanf("%d",&read->horario);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite o Canal(Globo,Band ou SBT): ");
gets(read->canal);
}

void checar_enquete(ENQUETE read)
{
int j=1,i=0;
printf("\n-------------------- ENQUETES %d --------------------------\n",j);
printf("\n Nome: %s",read.nome);
printf("\n Idade: %d",read.idade);
printf("\n Sexo: %s",read.sexo);
printf("\n Estado Civil: %s",read.estado_civil);
printf("\n Grau de Instrução: %s",read.grau);
printf("\n Horário da Entrevista: %d",read.horario);
printf("\n Canal: %s",read.canal);
printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------
-\n");
}
```

Comment: `&variavel` do lado de quem chama a função, `tipo *parametro` na assinatura da função

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
ENQUETE ler[10];
int i=0,opcao;
printf("\n-------------------- ENQUETE IBOPE --------------------\n");
do {
    menu();
    printf("\n Opção: ");
    scanf("%d",&opcao);
    if (opcao == 3) break;
    switch(opcao)
    {
    case 1:
        ler_dados(&ler[i]);
        i=i+1;
        break;
    case 2:
        checar_enquete(ler, i);
        break;
    case 3:
        return 0;
        break;
    }
} while (opcao != 3);
}


void ler_dados(ENQUETE *read)
{
printf("\n Digite o Nome: ");
scanf("%s", read->nome);fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite a idade: ");
scanf("%d", &read->idade);fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite o sexo(Masculino,Feminino ou Outro): ");
scanf("%s", read->sexo);fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite o Estado Civil(Solteiro,Casado,Viúvo ou Divorciado): ");
scanf("%s", read->estado_civil);fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite o Grau de Instrução(Fundamental,Médio,Superior,\n Mestrado ou Doutorado): ");
scanf("%s", read->grau);fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite o Horário da entrevista: ");
scanf("%d",&read->horario);fflush(stdin);
printf("\n Digite o Canal(Globo,Band ou SBT): ");
scanf("%s", read->canal);fflush(stdin);
}

void checar_enquete(ENQUETE read[10], int j)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < j) {
printf("\n-------------------- ENQUETES %d --------------------------\n",i);
printf("\n Nome: %s",read[i].nome);
printf("\n Idade: %d",read[i].idade);
printf("\n Sexo: %s",read[i].sexo);
printf("\n Estado Civil: %s",read[i].estado_civil);
printf("\n Grau de Instrução: %s",read[i].grau);
printf("\n Horário da Entrevista: %d",read[i].horario);
printf("\n Canal: %s",read[i].canal);
printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
i++;
}
}
```

Algumas considerações e uma possível solução para o teu problema:

- não é uma boa prática usar fgets pois ele traz problemas de segurança por não limitar o tamanho da entrada de dados;
- teu método ler estava correto com o &;
- modifiquei o teu método checar para passar pelo vetor e mostrar todos cadastrados.

Comment: Mas para eu ler os dados da struct dentro da função, eu tenho que passar com o &, sem ele não é possivel. E quando eu faço isso do mesmo jeito,mas com o "ler" sem ser um vetor, da certo... Estou com muita duvida nisso

Comment: Quando se trata de um vetor, não se usa o & pois ele trabalha internamente com ponteiros (já é passado o endereço para ser possível acessar as próximas posições de memória dentro da função). Mas quando se trata de uma variável simples (não vetor), se usa o & para passar o endereço de memória da variável. Resumindo, quando for vetor, não coloca o &.

Comment: Tenha atenção aos valores esperados pelas funções `ler_dados` e `checar_enquete`. A `ler_dados` espera um `ENQUETE*` logo está correto passar `&ler[i]`

Comment: Tens razão, @Isac. Vou ajustar o código dele aqui na resposta.